# What's wrong with this code to move css elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to move an element with javascript. I searched for a while and I think that this code should do the trick... but it does not, and I get no errors in the Console... anybody can help?

```
  <html><body>
  <script>
  function move1(){
    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('zzz');
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
        var item = cusid_ele[i];  
        var x=item.style.top;
        x+=10;
        item.style.top=x;
    }
  }
  function move2(){
    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('zzz');
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
        var item = cusid_ele[i];  
        var x=item.style["top"];
        x+=10;
        item.style["top"]=x;
    }
  }
  function move3(){
    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('zzz');
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
        var item = cusid_ele[i];  
        var x=item.style["top"];
        x+=10;
      item.style["top"]=x+'px';
    }
  }
  </script>
  <input type=button onclick="move1();" value="Move (1st way, with .top=x)!">
  <input type=button onclick="move2();" value="Move (2nd way, with [top]=x)!">
  <input type=button onclick="move3();" value="Move (3rd way, with [top]=xpx)!">
  <h3 class=zzz >Move me! (no inline style)</h3>
  <h3 class=zzz style="top: 50px;">Move me! (with inline style)</h3>
  </body></html>
```

By the way, I tried both FF and Chrome...

-- Accepted solution, I write it here so one can have a working example (thank you Adeneo!):

```
<script>
function move1(){
  var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('zzz');
  for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
      var item = cusid_ele[i];
      var x = parseInt( item.style.top, 10 );
      x+=10;
      item.style.top=x+'px';
  }
}  
</script>
<input type=button onclick="move1();" value="Move!">                       
<h3 class=zzz >I cant move! (no css positioning)</h3>
<h3 class=zzz style="position: relative; top: 50px;">I can move! (with css positioning)</h3>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can u share zzz class? Does it include absolute positioning?

Comment: there's no css behind, zzz class is "empty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
var x=item.style["top"];
```

returns the string `300px` etc, so

```
x += 10;
```

ends up being

```
300px10
```

so replace

```
var x=item.style.top;
```

with

```
var x = parseInt( item.style.top, 10 );
```

the same goes for setting styles

```
element.style.top = x + 'px';
```

You'll have to use a string with units, and to make the CSS actually do something, the elements must be positioned

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KQwLV/)

Comment: Does it work for you? For me it does not work even in this way...
    for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
      var item = cusid_ele[i];
      item.style["top"]='300px';
    }

Comment: got "the element must be positioned" and now it works! Thank you!